# Wordpress - get_permalink post id outside loop

Tags: php, loops

I've been struggling with this question for a while and although there's some topics regarding this subject I'm not sure how to implement it. It's regarding social buttons on homepage sharing the articles clicked on.

I have to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
    var bShareOpt = {url: "<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"};
</script>
```

which shows the permalink of the last ID instead of the link clicked on. If I add the `post_id` number

```
<?php echo get_permalink(2926); ?>
```

it shows the correct post.

Now this is because it happens outside the loop.

Other topics regarding getting post id outside the loop:
get-a-posts-id
wordpress-get-the-page-id-outside-the-loop
accessing-post-id-outside-of-the-loop-for-listing-child-pages

Using `get_queried_object_id` or `get_queried_object` is apparently another option to do so.

But unfortunately my PHP knowledge is very limited in order to glue the pieces together. I appreciate any help!

see [image](http://www.seomandarin.com/wp-content/uploads/article-share2.jpg) for what I mean:

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the ID of the page at the top of the template:

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

Then in your javascript, presumably after the loop:

```
var bShareOpt = {url: "<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"}
```

Not sure how your code is laid out, but hope this helps!

Comment: When I do that it returns the homepage/the page it's in

Comment: Now I see you added an image link to the question. I'm still confused about where the links are going, but if you want links in one post to be based on a different URL, you'll have to add post_meta fields, or use a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields and setup a 'relationship' between the two posts.

Comment: It's about the homepage of chinasurfreport dot com. It basically works the same as a facebook like butten you have underneath every article on a homepage like I did on the English version of that website